# svelte - using a nested json array with an Each function

Tags: arrays, json, sqlite, cordova, svelte

I am using [cordova-sqlite-porter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter) to export an SQLite table to JSON and then use the JSON exported using svelte.

My code to export the json is:

```
 let myDB = '';
 let vetdrugs = [];
 myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "vetcalculators.db", iosDatabaseLocation: "Documents" });

 var successFn = function(json, count){
  vetdrugs = JSON.stringify(json);
};
cordova.plugins.sqlitePorter.exportDbToJson(myDB, {
successFn: successFn,
dataOnly:true,
tables:['vetADrugs']
});
```

The resulting JSON is:

```
  {
  "data":{
  "inserts":{
     "vetADrugs":[
        {
           "drugradio":"single",
           "druglabel":"ml",
           "conc3":null,
           "Id":2,
           "dose":10,
           "conc1":null,
           "maximum":null,
           "desc":"",
           "title":"Test0",
           "notes":"",
           "minimum":null,
           "conc":100,
           "drugconc":"mg/ml",
           "conc2":null
        },
        {
           "drugradio":"single",
           "druglabel":"ml",
           "conc3":null,
           "Id":3,
           "dose":10,
           "conc1":null,
           "maximum":4,
           "desc":"",
           "title":"Test1",
           "notes":"",
           "minimum":2,
           "conc":100,
           "drugconc":"mg/ml",
           "conc2":null
        },
        {
           "drugradio":"single",
           "druglabel":"ml",
           "conc3":null,
           "Id":4,
           "dose":10,
           "conc1":null,
           "maximum":4,
           "desc":"",
           "title":"Test2",
           "notes":"",
           "minimum":2,
           "conc":100,
           "drugconc":"mg/ml",
           "conc2":null
        },
        {
           "drugradio":"single",
           "druglabel":"ml",
           "conc3":null,
           "Id":5,
           "dose":10,
           "conc1":null,
           "maximum":4,
           "desc":"",
           "title":"Test3",
           "notes":"",
           "minimum":2,
           "conc":100,
           "drugconc":"mg/ml",
           "conc2":null
        }
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, the JSON is exported as:

```
{
  "data":{
  "inserts":{
     "vetADrugs":[]...
```

And I am not able to export it as just:

```
{
"vetADrugs":[]...
```

Normally, in svelte I would use an each function like this:

```
{#each vetADrugs as drugs}
{drugs.title}
{/each}
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate the "data" and "inserts" part of the JSON into each function. Any help would be appreciated!

ADDENDUM:
I did try the following with no luck:

```
{#each vetdrugs.data.inserts.vetADrugs as drug}
<p>
    {drug.title}
</p>
{/each}
```

Comment: What you tried [just work](https://svelte.dev/repl/4bafd17ac179444b92623d806158fc47?version=3.42.1). Please be sure that the `vetdrugs` variable is the expected JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation in the each block.

```html
{#each data.inserts.vetADrugs as drug}
    <p>
        {drug.title}
    </p>
{/each}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried that with no luck. It failed with an error `Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data`    Since my json is stored in "vetdrugs",i.e.,  `let vetdrugs = JSON.stringify(json);`, I tried  {#each vetdrugs.data.inserts.vetADrugs as drug}. The "data" included in the JSON is confusing.

Comment: Why are you using JSON.stringify? That turns a JS object into a JSON string, you want the opposite to happen, try JSON.parse(json).

Comment: No reason other than I was following the code example used with sqlite-porter